# Text box intuitive user-interaction using focus listeners

Tags: java, performance

This code aims to replace labels used to explain a text box's container. This is done by adding a default string when the text box is considered empty to explain the purpose of the text box. However, when the text box is not considered empty, the text box will behave normally.

This is what I have written to solve my issue, I am posting it here for feedback and tips regarding anything to do with my code.

```
private void jTextFieldFocusGained(FocusEvent evt) {
    if(jTextField.getText().equals(TEXT_DEFAULT))
    {
        jTextField.setForeground(FOCUSED_COLOR);
        jTextField.setText(TEXT_FOCUSED);
    }
}
private void jTextFieldFocusLost(FocusEvent evt) {
    if(jTextField.getText().equals(TEXT_FOCUSED))
    {
        jTextField.setText(TEXT_DEFAULT);
        jTextField.setForeground(COLOR_DEFAULT);
    }
}
private final String TEXT_FOCUSED = "";
private final String TEXT_DEFAULT = "Type text here...";
private final Color COLOR_FOCUSED = Color.BLACK;
private final Color COLOR_DEFAULT = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in fact pretty good code, just some small nitpicks:

### Order

The fields should go before the methods; in fact, it should be near the front of the class, only after the `public static final` and `private static final` fields.

### Conventions

This piece of code:

> ```
> private void jTextFieldFocusGained(FocusEvent evt) {
>     if(jTextField.getText().equals(TEXT_DEFAULT))
>     {
>         jTextField.setForeground(FOCUSED_COLOR);
>         jTextField.setText(TEXT_FOCUSED);
>     }
> }
> private void jTextFieldFocusLost(FocusEvent evt) {
>     if(jTextField.getText().equals(TEXT_FOCUSED))
>     {
>         jTextField.setText(TEXT_DEFAULT);
>         jTextField.setForeground(COLOR_DEFAULT);
>     }
> }
> ```

1. In the `if` statement, if you don't put a new line before the method brace, you shouldn't put a new line before the `if` brace.
2. You are inconsistent in order. You set the foreground color first in one, and the text in another. Be consistent.
3. You should put 2 new lines between methods, and any non-related lines.
4. It is recommended to have a space after the `if`.

### Naming

`evt` should be `event`: names are concise names that shouldn't be abbreviated.

`jTextField` could just be `textField`. I know you are using a `JTextField`, but `textField` is a more readable name.

### Final Code:

```
private final String TEXT_FOCUSED = "";
private final String TEXT_DEFAULT = "Type text here...";
private final Color COLOR_FOCUSED = Color.BLACK;
private final Color COLOR_DEFAULT = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;

private void textFieldFocusGained(FocusEvent event) {
    if (textField.getText().equals(TEXT_DEFAULT)) {
        textField.setForeground(FOCUSED_COLOR);
        textField.setText(TEXT_FOCUSED);
    }
}

private void textFieldFocusLost(FocusEvent event) {
    if (textField.getText().equals(TEXT_FOCUSED)) {
        textField.setForeground(COLOR_DEFAULT);
        textField.setText(TEXT_DEFAULT);
    }
}
```